# Cant measure exception with Google Analytics in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics

I have the tracker set up like so

```
  <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('set', 'appName', 'My App');
    ga('set', 'appVersion', '1.2.1');
    ga('create', 'UA-NOT4U-4', 'auto');
  </script>
```

And it works fine for page views, however it does NOT work for exceptions. I can't seem to track them in the analytics dashboard despite sending them like so.

```
 (window as any).ga('send', {
     hitType: 'exception',
     exDescription: 'func failed',
     exFatal: false
  });
```

or

```
  (window as any).ga('send', 'exception', {
      exDescription: 'func failed'
  });
```

any ideas? I have a filter on a view for apps only, and that tracks exceptions in the mobile apps just fine. And the main view doesn't have an option for exceptions so I'm kinda lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

JFC...

I had the init functions in the wrong order... >.>

**Doesn't work**

```
ga('set', 'appName', 'My App');
ga('set', 'appVersion', '1.2.1');
ga('create', 'UA-NOT4U-4', 'auto');//<--wrong place, needs to be first
```

**Does work**

```
ga('create', 'UA-NOT4U-4', 'auto');
ga('set', 'appName', 'My App');
ga('set', 'appVersion', '1.2.1');
```